# How can I sync computer's time with Tor?

Tags: configuration, directory, time

I know about NTP, but since it's communication is NOT encrypted I don't want to use it.

The question is, how can I sync time with Tor proxy?

"HTP" protocol can achieve this, but it's not reliable(sometimes timeout due to Tor slowness).

How can I get reliable time from Tor's nodes quickly, anonymously, and correctly?

Comment: I'm using Windows, so Linux is no-go.
Any chance to get tlsget.exe(Windows) or other thing? Also I already read about Tails...

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at how Tails does [time syncing](https://tails.boum.org/contribute/design/Time_syncing/) via the Tor consensus file.
You can also use Jacob Applebaum's [tlsdate](https://github.com/ioerror/tlsdate) over Tor.

Comment: hm, does tor even connect when the system time is from early 1970? as far as i understand, tlsdate by default just does its thing over a regular tls connection...

Answer (score 0):

Really, if you're that paranoid that you won't even trust your network provider not to man-in-the-middle attack NTP traffic, then you may as well invest in a cheap GPS receiver.

Then once you've got a cheap GPS receiver, configure ntpd to use that to synchronise the time instead. GPS provides a very accurate time-source.

Of course someone could spoof GPS satellites, but then everyone in the area would be constantly getting lost when their navigation devices failed.